# Show that $x^3 \equiv 3 \pmod{p}$ is solvable if $p$ is of the form $6m+5$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

The question is:

> Show that $x^3 \equiv 3 \pmod{p}$ is solvable if $p$ is of the form $6m+5$. How many solutions are there?

Any help/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: On this site, posts that merely state a question are discouraged. You can improve the post by adding several kinds of information: where did you encounter the question, and what have you attempted?

Comment: It was a question in our Number Theory Final.

Comment: What sort of tools have you seen for dealing with questions like this? For instance, what do you know about the multiplicative group mod $p$?

Comment: A lot more is true: $x^3\equiv a\pmod{p}$ is solvable for any integer $a$, prime $p$ of the form $3k+2$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity#Integers) for a short simple proof).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It as simple as that:

The map $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^* \to (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*, x \mapsto x^3$ is injective, since there is no element of order $3$ in a group of size $6m+4$.

An injective self-mapping on a finite set is bijective. This also answers the second question.

Of course we can easily broaden the result without any more work: Whenver $m$ and $p-1$ are co-prime, we obtain a unique solution for the equation $x^m=a \pmod p$ for any $a$.

Comment: It is unclear for me why the fact that  there is no element of order 3 implies injectivity

Comment: Non-trivial elements in the kernel have order $3$.

Answer (score 2):

A broad hint: try Fermat's little theorem:

- What is $3^p$ congruent to,$\bmod p$?
- What is $3^{p-1}$ congruent to?
- Then what's $3^{2p-1}$ congruent to?
- In terms of $m$, what is $2p-1$?

As for the number of solutions, the fundamental theorem of algebra should help...

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain themselves?

Comment: It is not really conceptual. Any proof on this heavily relies on the fact, that $3$ and $6m+4$ are co-prime. Your proof does not point that out. It might seem loke coincidence for the unexperienced student, why this works. Furthermore the fundamental theorem of algebra does not really help at the number of solutions, besides telling you, there are at most $3$.